# Why is effective UID still not 0?

Tags: c, unix, permissions, uid

So I got this code below from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166817/using-the-setuid-bit-properly). However when I follow the commands:

```
sudo chown root:root a.out
sudo chmod u+s a.out
```

It still won't run with effective uid to 0.

This is the code:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L // Needed with glibc (e.g., linux).
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void report (uid_t real) {
    printf ("Real UID: %d Effective UID: %d\n", real, geteuid());
}

int main (void) {
    uid_t real = getuid();
    report(real);
    seteuid(real);
    report(real);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Real UID: 1000 Effective UID: 1000
Real UID: 1000 Effective UID: 1000
```

Where I supposed it should have been:

```
Real UID: 1000 Effective UID: 0
Real UID: 1000 Effective UID: 1000
```

Comment: Show the output of the program.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart just edited it. Also showed what I expect!

Comment: Not repeatable with Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.9

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I got no idea what you said there but I run Ubuntu 16.10 kernel version 4.8. If the OS has something to do this my problem please some with different OS doesn't have it.

Comment: Your a.out might be on a filesystem whose mount options disable setuid programs. Examples of these options are `nosuid`, `group`, `owner`, `user`, and `users`.

Comment: Please cd to the directory where that a.out is. Run `df .` to get the mount point. Run `mount | grep themountpoint` and see what the filesystem type and mount options are.

Comment: It gave me the `nosuid` thing :(  Does this mean I need to create a new user and run it on that other user?

Comment: `nosuid` applies to all users. Your system administrator can judge whether to remove that `nosuid` mount option, after taking security considerations into account. Or you can try your tests on another filesystem.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick how to remove the nosuid?

Comment: The mount options could be in a few different configuration files, depending on your operating system distribution and where the storage is physically located (for instance, if the drive is removable or imported from a network server). It's probably more on-topic to ask how to do this over on http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently as @MarkPlotnick said.

> cd to the directory where that a.out is. Run df . to get the mount
>   point. Run mount | grep themountpoint and see what the filesystem type
>   and mount options are.

If there is something saying `nosuid` then you need to remount that part of filesystem without the nosuid flag.

This website [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-nodev-nosuid-noexec-options-to-temporary-storage-partitions/) gives a good explanation about how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The getuid function returns the real user id only. The real user id of user process is still 1000. The 1000 is stored in the real variable.

So, while calling of seteuid function you again sets the 1000 as the effective user id.But actually you have to set the 0 in that place.  So only the effective user id doesn't changed.

Try the below it will works fine.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L // Needed with glibc (e.g., linux).
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void report (uid_t real) {
    printf ("Real UID: %d Effective UID: %d\n", real, geteuid());
}

int main (void) {
    uid_t real = getuid();
    report(real);
    seteuid(0);
    report(real);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well the thing is that its euid should be 0 at first I don't have to set it 0 and if it is not 0 it cannot become 0. Else it would be a privilege escalation vulnerability. Btw I ran your program too and same thing. Im running  Ubuntu 16.10  kernel version 4.8